# How to extract characters of particular length from a given string in python Regex

Tags: python, regex

How to extract characters of particular length from a given string in python Regex

Hi I have records like,

Eg:

1. Health Insurance PortabilityNEG Ratio
2. Health Insurance PortabilityNEGRatio
3. Health Insurance PortabilityNEG NEGRatio

Here I need to extract NEG as my to write a regex in python like

```
Portability(.+?) Ratio,
Portability(.+?)Ratio
```

where I first "NEG" after Portability is my valuewhich i should get. The first and Second records give me correct output as "NEG". But in my third record I get "NEG NEG" which is a wrong value.

I need to get only "NEG" for third record also.Should I give the length of the first three character to take only "NEG".
If so, Kindly let me know how can I write the regex according to that?

Comment: Is `NEG` always a 3 char substring? Use `Portability(.{3}).*?Ratio`. See https://regex101.com/r/xdDqxp/1. Or are they always uppercase letters? Then use `[A-Z]{3}` instead of `.{3}`.

Comment: Is NEG always associated with Portability?

Answer (score 0):

The `.` means any character at all, and the `+` symbol mean "at least one" but does not specify an upper limit. You want `\w{n}`, where `\w` means character and `n` means number of occurences.

Also, note that `\w` includes arithmetic digits, so if you only want letters, you'd better use `[a-zA-Z]{3}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to extract *any* 3 chars right after `Portability` use

```
re.findall(r"Portability(.{3}).*?Ratio", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xdDqxp/1)

If these are uppercase letters, replace `.{3}` with `[A-Z]{3}`.

**Details**:

- `Portability` - a literal char sequence
- `(.{3})` - Capturing group 1: exactly 3 chars (any chars other than line break chars if `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` modifier is not used) since `{3}` is a limiting quantifier matching the number of occurrences defined inside `{...}`
- `.*?Ratio` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier) up to the first `Ratio` substring.

The `re.findall` only returns captured values, so you will only get `NEG`.